# React testing library test controlled checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I am trying to test a controlled checkbox with react testing library and the checkbox behaves differently in the testing environment than in the browser.

When I click the checkbox in the browser the onChange is fired with e.target.checked having the inverse value of it's current state.

When I click the checkbox with the testing library's userEvent.click function, onChange is fired with e.target.checked having it's current value.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was accessing the value on the event object after it had had the checked value updated